# Spark join not working due to an org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have case classes like these and I am trying to join the datasets created by the objects of the case classes.

```
 case class RemoteCopyGroup(
    ts: Long,
    systemId: String,
    name: String,
    groupId: Int,
    role: String,
    mode: String,
    remoteGroupName: String)

    case class RemoteCopyGroupTarget(
     ts: Long,
     systemId: String,
     groupId: Int,
     targetName: String,
     groupName: String)


 val rcg1 = RemoteCopyGroup(
    ts = 1000,
    systemId = "ABC",
    name = "ABC",
    groupId = 100,
    role = "ABC",
    mode = "ABC",
    remoteGroupName = "ABC")

  val rcg2 = RemoteCopyGroup(
    ts = 1000,
    systemId = "ABC",
    name = "ABC",
    groupId = 101,
    role = "ABC",
    mode = "ABC",
    remoteGroupName = "ABC")

  val rcg3 = RemoteCopyGroup(
    ts = 1000,
    systemId = "XYZ",
    name = "ABC",
    groupId = 101,
    role = "ABC",
    mode = "ABC",
    remoteGroupName = "ABC")

  val ds1 = List(rcg1, rcg2, rcg3).toDS()

   val rcgt1 = RemoteCopyGroupTarget(ts = 2000, systemId = "ABC", groupId = 50, 
       targetName = "ABC", groupName = "XYZ")
   val rcgt2 = RemoteCopyGroupTarget(ts = 3000, systemId = "DEF", groupId = 101, 
       targetName = "ABC", groupName = "XYZ")

    val ds2 = List(rcgt1, rcgt2).toDS()

    val joined = ds1.join(ds2, ds1.col("groupId") === ds2.col("groupId"), "inner")

    joined.show()
```

However I get an error

```
   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve 
   column name "groupId" among (value)
```

Although I have `groupId` present in the schema !! How to fix this ? Should I write something to make 'groupId' explicitly recognized ?

Comment: the code is working on my local, the only thing i added in the code is sparksession and import spark.implicit._ , which will allow you to convert Seq to Dataset

Comment: I even have that one imported !! but still does not work

Comment: when I do print schema I get root
       |-- value: binary (nullable = true)

22/02/22 12:13:20 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 40.134827 ms
root
 |-- ts: long (nullable = false)
 |-- systemId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- groupId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- targetName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- groupName: string (nullable = true)

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "groupId" among (value)